# java.lang.NullPointerException Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I got this from a tutorial and made some changes but I'm unable to figure out why it's pointing to a null object.

Here are the codes:

**HomeActivity.java**

```
final DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.token_table).child(Common.user_workers_table).child(stringWorkerType);
    dbRef.orderByKey().equalTo(workerId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Token token = ds.getValue(Token.class);

                //Make raw payload - convert LatLng to json
                String json_lat_lng = new Gson().toJson(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
                String workerToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
                Notification notification = new Notification(workerToken, json_lat_lng);
                Sender content = new Sender(token.getToken(), notification);
                //IFCMService mService;
                mService.sendMessage(content).enqueue(new Callback<FCMResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<FCMResponse> call, Response<FCMResponse> response) {
                        if(response.body().success == 1) {
                            Log.d("LOG/I", "Request sent.");
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Request not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
```

**IFCMService.java**

```
public interface IFCMService {

@Headers({
        "Content-Type:application/json",
        "Authorization:key=AAAAJorGt9o:APA91bFgAhEUL9oCFSD9wnLEflqw5hip6Q7kZ7E4JPX7mY5NLTb78lnvlbhMikojpa2Gp-2LnVE1pfXNhyXY25JFj-omR9_OgDN5qcj2rvqUeaYIolhi1uNKa2o3sErk-15PjojYEy7z"
})

@POST("fcm/send")
Call<FCMResponse> sendMessage(@Body Sender body);
}
```

**FCMResponse.java**

```
public class FCMResponse {

public long multicast_id;
public int success;
public int failure;
public int canonical_ids;
public List<Result> results;

public FCMResponse() {
}

public FCMResponse(long multicast_id, int success, int failure, int canonical_ids, List<Result> results) {
    this.multicast_id = multicast_id;
    this.success = success;
    this.failure = failure;
    this.canonical_ids = canonical_ids;
    this.results = results;
}

public long getMulticast_id() {
    return multicast_id;
}

public void setMulticast_id(long multicast_id) {
    this.multicast_id = multicast_id;
}

public int getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(int success) {
    this.success = success;
}

public int getFailure() {
    return failure;
}

public void setFailure(int failure) {
    this.failure = failure;
}

public int getCanonical_ids() {
    return canonical_ids;
}

public void setCanonical_ids(int canonical_ids) {
    this.canonical_ids = canonical_ids;
}

public List<Result> getResults() {
    return results;
}

public void setResults(List<Result> results) {
    this.results = results;
}
}
```

**Sender.class**

```
public class Sender {
public String to;
public Notification notification;

public Sender() {
}

public Sender(String to, Notification notification) {
    this.to = to;
    this.notification = notification;
}

public String getTo() {
    return to;
}

public void setTo(String to) {
    this.to = to;
}

public Notification getNotification() {
    return notification;
}

public void setNotification(Notification notification) {
    this.notification = notification;
}
}
```

It's an app like uber, what this codes supposed to be doing is when the driver/client app request and a driver/worker is available, it will give a notification to the driver/worker. But it does nothing and I'm getting an error at

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at 
com.fixitph.client.HomeActivity$22$1.onResponse(HomeActivity.java:1129)
```

1129 is the ***if(response.body().success == 1) {*** line
Let me know if you need more information on this. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: As a non-Android programmer, my suspicion is that either 'response' or 'response.body()' are null. Determining which situation it is, will help you refine your question.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question because I know what the error means, the issue is that I can't find out why it's getting nothing from the object it's calling when I believe, there's a data on it.

Answer (score 0):

The value is Null(No data). So Null pointer exception coming. Log your Response and check data is coming or not

Answer (score 0):

Your `response.body()` might be null and you are trying to access a field of a null object.

Try this:

```
if(response.isSuccessful()) {
    Log.d("LOG/I", "Request sent.");
} else {
    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Request not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This is because either your `FCMResponse` class is not mapped to the class model correctly or you are returning a null value. Make sure `FCMResponse` is mapped and can be deserialized correctly.

You can use `@SerializedName("name_here")` if you need to differ serialized field names from class field names.

**EDIT**

I would call the endpoint using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or any other similar tool and see the server's response body. I would then compare the `FCMResponse` class fields and field names with the response body to decide if they match exactly or not.

You `FCMResponse` class actually represents the body of your response not the response itself. Maybe you are mistaken there.

Comment: Hi Mert, can you help me figure out what response.body should have?

Comment: @BlueCollar, Hi, check my edited answer. If you can get the server's response and update your question, we can help more.